# how to put a float number inside an char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

i want to put some float numbers inside a string in C for an arduino project.
but i don't have any idea that can simply do this and not take lot storage(because of using arduino with 8kb).

this is my string:

```c
char http_cmd[] = "GET /index.php?lat=*****&long=***** HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                  "Host: 39c309ae.ngrok.io\r\n"
                  "\r\n";
```

and i want to replace that *****s with numerical variables like :

```c
float latitude = 36.423156, longitude = 48.526484;
```

Comment: Use memcpy, pass it the address of your character array which must be at least 4 bytes in length and the address of the float, with sizeof(float).  This will copy the binary representation of how the float is represented in memory, not a human readable version.  You can then copy this from the character array back to a float by doing the same and swapping the pointers.

Comment: see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/

Comment: @SPlatten I think he wants the float to be formatted into text.

Comment: @uneven_mark, then in that case a simple sprintf with the format as "%.#f" where # is the number of decimals, the buffer should be large enough for the formatted number + 1.

Comment: in this case, i want that two seperated string lines in http_cmd to stay! but with sprintf i've tried, they lost! how can i add them in this current format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sprintf()

```
float latitude = 36.423156, longitude = 48.526484;
sprintf( http_cmd, "GET /index.php?lat=%f&long=%f HTTP/1.0\r\n 
         Host: 39c309ae.ngrok.io\r\n\r\n", latitude, longitude);
```

You can compose your own string by printing chars, integers, float... And you can decide how many digits print to the array (in this case 4 digits).

Comment: worth noting: `%.4f` will print *up to* four digits *after the decimal* -- which is an important distinction when deciding how large to make the `http_cmd` buffer. also worth pointing out the `snprintf` function which can provide more buffer safety if it's available in the OP's stdlib.

Comment: this works but previous strings in http_cmd are lost! that two lines : 
                  "Host: 39c309ae.ngrok.io\r\n"
                  "\r\n";
are so important! how to add them! because they must not be linear in a string!! and i dont know why just i got errors!

Comment: You can compose the string like a normal printf. The difference is printing to another string instead of stdout

Comment: Note that sprintf is MASSIVE for a small uC, depending on what he's trying to do.